# Sitecore custom user profile is not supporting inheritance?

Tags: user-profile, helix

I'm trying to extend existing User Profile Template with some project specific fields. I thought it will be handy to do it by template inheritance. But seems like only fields directly declared in Profile Template are visible in User Manager. Please take a look on the screens below.

- We have _UserProfile which holds base set of fields,
- I created interface template _Test_UserProfile with project specific fields.

  - I created Test_UserProfile template that inherits from _UserProfile and _Test_UserProfile
    _ I added one field directly in Test_UserProfile
  - then I created Profile Item that inherits from Test_UserProfile
  - when I create user that uses my new Profile only directly declared fields are visible

Do you guys know if there is any way to make this work?

thanks!

[image: Profile template builder contains one directly declared field]

[image: Profile inherits from 2 other Profile Templates]

[image: In User Editor, profile tab, you can see only directly declated field]

Answer (score 2):

Can you try bellow solution :

1)Copy the attached [Sitecore.Support.350672](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oo9mb6sed56mjkm/Sitecore.Support.350672.dll?dl=0) file to the bin folder

2)Open the Website\sitecore\shell\Applications\Security\EditUser\EditUser.xaml.xml file and implement the below change:

Comment

```
<Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Security.EditUser Application="Security/Edit User" x:inherits="Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Security.EditUser.EditUserPage,Sitecore.Client">-->
```

and add next line of code:

```
<Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Security.EditUser Application="Security/Edit User" x:inherits="Sitecore.Support.Shell.Applications.Security.EditUser.EditUserPage, Sitecore.Support.350672">
```

Comment: Thanks @SitecoreClimber, this looked promising but unfortunatelly Im getting error: `The class includes the field 'TabStrip', but its type (ComponentArt.Web.UI.TabStrip) is not compatible with the type of control (Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Tabstrip). (method: Sitecore.Web.UI.XamlSharp.Xaml.ControlCompilers.ControlCompiler.Bind(CompilerOptions options, Type controlType)).` Any idea what it might be? My sitecore version is Sitecore.NET 8.2 (rev. 160729) if thats any help

Comment: Yes can be version.

Comment: I compared EditUserPage.cs that you sent me to the one in my sitecore version and looks like yours is using ComponentArt.Web.UI library. Does this fix come from public Support ticket?

Comment: Yes is from sitecore support